# Mask Password Plugin is still displaying password in console output

Tags: jenkins, passwords, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, masking

We need to mask the passwords from pipeline job, we used mask password 2.10.1, credentials and credentials binding plugin. But still we are seeing the password getting exposed in Job console output.

**Code:**

```
node {
{
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'c6989249-6a8d-4618-9fd7-012720791e12', usernameVariable: 'artifact_id', passwordVariable: 'artifact_pwd']]){
                echo "password masking"
                sh "echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd "
}}
```

**output:**

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
password masking
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ echo **** 'Test!123'
**** Test!123
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: What version of Jenkins and plugins are you using? They have a lot of mentions on the backlog about masking of pwd's. And those are slowly fixed.

Comment: Jenkins is 2.89.3 and plugins are Mask Password 2.10,credentials plugin 2.1.16, credentials binding plugin 1.15

Comment: btw, did you check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834768/password-shows-in-plain-text-using-jenkins-credentials-plugin?rq=1?

Comment: There's little strange, $artifact_id be masked, but $artifact_pwd unmasked. If jenkins or plugin has issue, the both should be masked or unmasked.  Please double check you define `artifact_pwd` as Groovy variable in somewhere in your whole pipeline script.  Or change `"` to `'` on `sh 'echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd'` to see what will be output,

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Groovy variable `artifact_pwd` be defined/created in your whole pipeline script during pipeline running.

Additionally, you use `"` to wrapper string in line: `sh "echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd "`, this will lead Groovy do variable substitution firstly, so `$artifact_pwd` will be replaced to the value of same name Groovy variable.

If you don't expect variable substitution on string, you can use `'` or `'''` to wrapper string as below:

```
sh 'echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd' 
//or 
sh '''echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd'''
```

You can replace `sh "echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd"` to `sh 'echo $artifact_id $artifact_pwd'`, and run again to see what will output.